# Meteor React Modify State of Multiple Components

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, state

Using Meteor 1.3 and React, I've made the following main component:

```
//imports
export default class Show extends TrackerReact(Component) {

  renderOptions() {
    return this.options().map((option) => (
      <Option key={ option._id } option={ option }/>
    ));
  }

  options() {
    return Options.find({}).fetch();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <ul>
          { this.renderOptions() }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I have the following `Option` component:

```
export default class Option extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      disabled: false
    };
  }

  vote() {
    this.setState({ disabled: true });
  }

  renderButton() {
    return this.state.disabled ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-default';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <button disabled={ this.state.disabled ? 'disabled' : '' } type="button" className={this.renderButton()} onClick={this.vote.bind(this)}>
          Vote
        </button>
        <span> { this.props.option.text }</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

Option.PropTypes = {
  option: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

How can I make it so when I click the button (which invokes the component's `vote()` method) on any one of the options rendered by the `Show` component the `disabled` state of each button is set to `true`? 
Basically, I am rendering out a few buttons for the user to click, and once he clicks one, I want to disable all of the others. Therefore, I need to set the state of all buttons to `disabled` when one is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a React question than a Meteor question, but what you would need to do is to declare your function in your parent component and then pass it down as a prop to your child component. Then inside your child component you can call that function with `this.props.funcName`.

So in your example you'd want to declare the state in your `Show` component (or higher if it affects other components) and then pass down a function that updates the state in your parent component. This state would then be passed down as props to your `Option` component.

Let me know if that isn't clear

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to be clear, I would have to pass down the function that updates the state of the parent component as a prop to the Option components?

Comment: Yes exactly. You'll need to keep track of what option component is enabled/disabled in the parent. Possibly some kind of ID